# Threading and paralell MySQL access (pyMySQL)

Tags: python, mysql, multithreading, python-3.x, pymysql

I try to understand how threading works.

Here is my code that runs infinitely:

```
while(True):
    # Check All Streams if they are online AND with which Summoner #
    checkStreams()

    # Check if we have new finished games #
    if newGames:
         getMatchHistory()
         updateSummonerStats()

    # Update Online Stats #
    updateOnline()
```

`checkStreams()` is a rather small function, but `getMatchHistory()` and `updateSummonerStats()` take quite some time and they don't run very often.
So the idea is to run those 2 functions in 2 seperate threads.

From what I read here http://softwareramblings.com/2008/06/running-functions-as-threads-in-python.html my approach was this:

These Functions should run is seperate threads but the functions after should continue immediately

```
if newGames:   
     t1 = threading.Thread(target=getMatchHistory)
     t1.start()
     t2 = threading.Thread(target=updateSummonerStats)
     t2.start()
```

Now I have this issues: Both threaded functions access my MySQL Database and that causes this error: `Packet sequence number wrong - got 0 expected 2` and many similar.

Is this even the right approach for paralell function or is there a better solution?

Comment: Do you have a `t1.join()` and `t2.join()` later on in the script?  What's your full stack trace on the error?  What version of PyMySql are you using? Looking at the github issues on PyMySql, this is a common issue when using pyMySql with multithreading. Source: https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL/issues/511

Comment: From what I understand t1.join makes it wait for t1? I throw an exception: `EXCEPTION IN (C:/Projects/PyCharm/ls/crawl.py, LINE 151 "datetime.now()"): Packet sequence number wrong - got 101 expected 1` Line 151 is `cursor.execute("MY MYSQL QUERY")`. PyMySQL is 0.7.9 so supposedly the issue should be resolved?

Comment: Yes, `.join()` makes it wait for that thread.  You can add the `.join()` after you call `t2` so that both threads run.  You want both threads to join before running `updateOnline()` otherwise it'll try to update before the information comes back.  Try adding the `.join()` statements for both threads before `updateOnline()` and see if that fixes anything, if you haven't already.